# Submit Button is not rendered in Symfony 2.x Form

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I'm creating a from using Symfony Form builder, and rendering it using twig.

Here is my form builder code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
    ->add('name', 'text', array(
      'required' => TRUE,
    ))
    ->add('link', 'text', array(
      'required' => TRUE,
    ))
    ->add('submit', 'submit', array(
      'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm custom-btn'
      )
    ))
    ;
  }
```

And my twig template is like this:

```
{{ form_start(form)}}
<div>
  {{ form_label(form.name) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
</div>

<div>
  {{ form_label(form.link) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.link) }}
</div>

<div>
  {{ form_widget(form.submit) }}
</div>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

In this case, I'm getting everything as expected, except the submit button. Instead of custom submit button created in form builder, it is rendering default submit button with a label `create`.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it is some issue with 'submit' name. For example, next example works:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        .... // your fields here
        ->('my_button', 'submit');
}
```

Then in the twig template:

```
<div>
  {{ form_widget(form.my_button) }}
</div>
```

**UPDATED** : according to http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html you can use `{{ form_widget(form.submit, {'label': 'submit'}) }}`. So next lines renders submit with '**submit**' name:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.text) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.code) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.submit, {'label': 'submit'}) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

And you don't need to add submit to your FormType in this case.

Comment: It works perfectly. But in that case, form also renders default button as well. How to avoid that?

Comment: It is coming always :(. If I remove form_start and form_end, then only default one is coming. And after removing them if I use custom name for submit button, then only custom button is coming. But of course, it won't work because form tag won't be rendered in that case.

Comment: ok. Adding properties to twig form works. But is it a good practice to add properties in twig form directly instead of adding in FormBuilder?

Comment: @niyasc why not? I have the same question: is it good practice to add classes in the twig directly? having business logic in the template is bad practice, but adding label or some attr is not business logic.